# Service Layer in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm building a small application in Spring and Spring Data JPA.
I need serval layer. I don't know if I'm doing well.

Here is an example:
**POJO**

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long Id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private int price;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "Id=" + Id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    Product findByName(String name);
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    Product getProductById(String productId);
    void addProduct(Product product);
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public interface ProductService  {

    List<Product> getAllProducts();
    Product getProductById(String productId);
    void addProduct(Product product);
}
```

**REPOSITORY IMPLEMENTATION**

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.getAllProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(String productId) {
        return productRepository.getProductById(productId);
    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productRepository.addProduct(product);

    }

}
```

It is a good?
Unless How create communication with database in Spring?

Comment: What is the benefit of having Service Interface here?

Comment: @Pawan The use of service interface here is that if someone has to deliver ProductServices in a different way i.e by using a different database or using different business logic then by implementing the interface gives a reason to return the same output without affecting the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if I'd review this I'd add the following:

- The Id field in Product could be renamed id to follow java convention
- Generally it's a good practice to have equals & hashcode methods overridden.

As for the database connection it depends on which Spring & database you are using, does it happen to be Spring Boot?

Comment: @MaciejDymarczyk No problem
Then it's very simple, assuming you use a mysql database you need: 
1. Add dependency 
`<dependency>`

           `<groupId>mysql</groupId>`
            `<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>`
       ` </dependency>`

2. Add connection properties in application.yml file
`spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB_NAME`
`spring.datasource.username=YOUR_USERNAME`
`spring.datasource.password=YOUR_PASSWORD`
For more check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-mysql)